# How to disable the 'Open Link in New Tab' in the browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

How do I disable/remove the 'Open Link in New Tab' option in the right-click menu of the browser? 
If this is not possible with javascript etc then is there a way to modify what happens when the user clicks on this link, for example, display an alert or prevent the tab from loading..?

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't try to undermine a users intention, even if it isn't the flow that you are gearing yourself towards.  Alternatively, you could make the href "#" and use an 'onclick' handler to actually perform the page transition, thus eliminating the ability of the user to use that function.

Comment: Why would you want to interfere with your users browser like that?  It should be up to ME what tab your link opens to.

Comment: @Inuyasha My app currently displays an error if the link is opened in a new tab. It is designed to load the content into a div on the same page. If this wasn't the case then believe me I would have no wish to "interfere".

Comment: As a user I would prefer that type of feature be triggered from a button rather than a link. I expect links to work in a more standard way including giving me the option to right-click for the menu or to middle-click to open directly in a new tab.

Comment: @grainne: Then perhaps a better way would to make open link in new tab work rather than disabling it.

Comment: @icktoofay: point taken that it should be possible to open in a new tab, however currently an error is displaying, so until I fix the main issue, I just want this as temporary solution. also from a tech point of view I was curious if this was possible. I was not asking this question looking for opinions about usability.

Comment: this wont work when you click by mouse middle button or hold CTRL and click on a link. how to those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have solved the main issue now, quite easily as it turned out just by passing the query string of the href to an ajax function.

I probably should have explained in my question that what I wanted was intended only as a temporary measure. Anyway thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 15):

The ability to open a link in a new tab/window is native functionality of many browsers.  If you do not wish to allow this type of activity, then you need to notify the browser that your link is not truly a link.  The easiest way to do so is to remove the `href` attribute from your `a` element.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://google.com">Can be opened in new tab/window</a>
<a>Cannot be opened in new tab/window</a>
```

Now there are some other things that the browser may be doing for you by default when it sees a link.  If you have not defined any styling of `a` elements, it's likely that your new fancy pseudo-link will not appear with a link font-color, pointer, and underline.  You can go ahead and do that easily enough.

**CSS:**

```
a {
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

That hopefully answers the question of how you disable/remove the 'Open Link in New Tab' option in the right-click menu of the browser.  For some extra credit though I'm going to assume that you probably want the link to still function like a regular link when clicked.  Feel free to use some JavaScript to make that happen.  Here's an example using jQuery:

**JavaScript:**

```
$("body").on("click", "a[data-href]", function() {
    var href = $(this).data("href");
    if (href) {
        location.href = href;
    }
});
```

**Modified Html:**

```
<a href="http://google.com">Can be opened in new tab/window</a>
<a data-href="http://google.com">Cannot be opened in new tab/window</a>
```

**Modified CSS:**

```
a[href], a[data-href] {
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

### 2019

I'll highlight 2 important comments:

1. **nnnnnn** @ Aug 10 '11 at 5:49 :

   > As a user I would prefer that type of feature be triggered from a
   >   button rather than a link. I expect links to work in a more standard
   >   way including giving me the option to right-click for the menu or to
   >   middle-click to open directly in a new tab.
2. **Pars** @ Dec 21 '13 at 13:10 :

   > this wont work when you click by mouse middle button or hold CTRL and
   >   click on a link. how to those cases.

***It's up to the browser to decide whether it gets the link-behavior or not.***

Some modern browser (like Chrome) will consider it a link if **all** the below conditions matches:

1. It's an `<a>...</a>` tag (not `span`, `div`, `button`, etc).
2. It has `href` attribute.
3. `href` attribute is not empty.

The below **will get** the link-behavior:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com">Click Here</a>
```

The below **will NOT get** the link-behavior:

```
<a>Not link because no href</a>
<a href="">Not link because empty href</a>
<span>Not link because not "a" tag</span>
<span href="http://www.website.com">Not link because not "a" tag again</span>
```

#### Important Note:

Again, ***it's up to the browser to decide***. Some old/stupid browsers may give it link-behavior if ***ANY of the 3 conditions above matches!***

#### Conclusion

If it's a link then use `<a href="some_link">...</a>`. If it's not a link then use something else, like `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why would some one downvote your question, what you need to google is how to hijack events using javascript. You can very well show an alert when you click a link and stop it from working. jQuery is a populat JS toolkit and has a method to stop default events on an element, in plain English, using jQuery you can stop a hyperlink from working it and show an alert as well. This link http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ can help you further. Regarding disabling the context menu that appears on right clicking on a webpage, yes that is very much possible. I am not a JS ninja so can't comment if you can remove an item from context menu but IMO, it should not be possible.

Comment: this wont work when you click by mouse middle button or hold CTRL and click on a link, how to prevent these cases?