# How to disable mouse middle button click to open in a new tab or new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, mousewheel

I am trying to disable right and middle button of mouse so that it cant open new window or tab when click on any menu or hyperlink. Below javascript code works fine for right button but not working for middle button. Middle button of mouse gets captured but still new window or tab opens when click on hyperlink or menu.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.layers) {           
        document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
        document.onmousedown = function () {
            return false;
        };
    }
    else {
        document.onmouseup = function (e) {
            if (e != null && e.type == "mouseup") {      

                if (e.which == 3) {
                    alert("Sorry..... Right click Is Disabled!!!!");                        
                        return false;
                }

                if(e.which===2)
                {
                   e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    alert("Sorry..... Mouse Scroll click Is Disabled!!!!");
                    return false;
                }
                else if(e.button===4)
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    alert("Sorry..... Mouse Scroll click Is Disabled!!!!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Its not woking for firefox, chrome and IE.

Comment: Are you also disabling "normal" left click?  Middle click = ctrl left click  (or shift left click, browser dependent)

Comment: The question is not exactly a duplicate, but this answer will definitely help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354454/178551

Answer (score 2):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event) the `auxclick` event handles the "open link in new tab with middle mouse button" behaviour.

The following code will prevent the middle click behaviour on the entire page.

```
window.addEventListener("auxclick", (event) => {
  if (event.button === 1) event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you want to disable it for a certain link only, just replace the event listener target (window) with a reference to the specific node.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
document.onmousedown= function (e) {
    if( e.which == 2 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("middle button"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Durgesh. But its not working.

Comment: @KishorKulkarni I have updaetd the answer Please look into it